# Topicality of Black Scholes Option pricing model

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

It seems to me that for math stack exchange, problems dealing with the Black Scholes option pricing model are on topic. Are they? If they are not, I think they should be. Please comment.

For example, is this question on topic:
[Finding a price of a call option using the Black Scholes model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668199/finding-a-price-of-a-call-option-using-the-black-scholes-model)

Comment: This needs some context.  As a stochastic differential equation, of course Black-Scholes is on topic.  To be sure, the more finance based the question is, the less on topic it will be for this site.

Comment: How about a question where you are asked to apply the Black-Scholes model to find the value of a call option?

Comment: Are you asking about [your question from earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668199/finding-a-price-of-a-call-option-using-the-black-scholes-model)?  If so, you should link to that in this post.

Comment: In any case, I'd say that asking us to check a purely mechanical set of computations is off topic.  It's just a matter of plugging numbers into a pre-packaged formula.  There, I thought it was sufficient to just provide you a link to a good online calculator that could verify your computation.  Beyond that, what is there to say about it?

Comment: @lulu I am and I will add a link to the question in my question.

Comment: Searching for "black scholes pricing" returns plenty of hits; e.g., [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4654086/742), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4634742/742), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4514338/742). So clearly some questions about it are on-topic. But if it is just a matter of verifying that a plug-and-chug is correct, then you will likely see it closed as not within the scope of the site. Much like questions about multiplication or the multplication algorithm are on-topic, but a post asking us to verify that $7\times 13$ really is $91$ will likely be closed.

Comment: There's also a SE for quantitative finance if you want to read more there